# How do I access files on an external hard drive?

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk, ping

edited 02-25:
I thank @Anthon for his replies. I still do not, however, understand the meaning or the how of "pinging" ("Once you update your Q, ping the commenters..."). I also do not understand the meaning of "If you don't know what he means ask him in a comment under his" (?).  I do hope he and the others excuse the fact that I've not contacted them directly about this updated question.

As well, thank you @Jenny D for your (patient and clear) instructions and information. I've printed them out and will use.

@ganessh: It is a NTFS drive

@Zelda - I pulled the drive because the computer in which it was installed had a failing (well, failed) motherboard, and I needed to get to the data. I had no problems with the drive when it was still in the (alive) computer.

@Babin Ionston-I downloaded the ntfs3g pkg (and vague instructions) but am having a difficult time with the installation. I will however, keep trying, and if unsuccessful, will write down the challenges and bring the question here.

It would be *enormously* beneficial for new members to receive a "write this/not that" message to make it very clear what information is needed by members to respond to a question (and I don't remember receiving such when I signed up, but perhaps I did). Although I'm quite honored with the patience shown by most of the folks who have responded to my question, I think doing so would save everyone time.

All: I will try out these suggestions (and instructions) and report back. Thank you.

=============

I have a lot of files on an external hard drive that I wish to access on my (now) Linux-based computer. The computer is now running Mint 16 (Cinnamon). The drive is a SATA drive I pulled from my Windows computer. That computer ran Windows 7. 
The problems I experience are:

1. The drive appears on my desktop, and all of the folders on it (I believe) do display in the folder list.  I can access some folders quickly (and see the contents) but not others (including the folder with the files I need--mostly Word/Excel files). These files are in a folder that was formerly in the Users folder on my Windows computer.
2. My computer freezes when I click on this file (and this is the largest folder--approx 12 GB) I see a spinning disk and (I think) the word "processing"above it. Then the computer locks up: the cursor freezes, or doesn't freeze, but I can't close the window. I receive a message (I think it says "accessing") and a spinning disk, but the files do not open, and the computer freezes. I then have to reboot.
3. I also tried copying the files to the computer, but was not able to do so (the freezing began).

My question: What do I need to access these files?

Also (and once again), what information should I provide you all to make answering my question(s) easier? Please note that I am new to Linux, so do not assume that I understand terms (like ping) or abbreviations that may be familiar to you.

Comment: In what way can't you access these files? Can you see the directory they're in but can't open it for example?

Comment: If your unable to access files/folders to permissions, then open terminal navigate to that folder's parent and try this
chmod 777 file/foldername

Comment: What is the filesystem of the hard drive?

Comment: Why did you pull the drive out of your windows computer. Did you have problems accessing the files or starting Win7?

Answer (score 8):

First, you need to find the actual path to the drive and the type of file system on it.

Open a terminal window and type `mount`. You will get a list that looks something like

```
[jenny@willow ~]$ mount
/dev/ad0s1a on / (ufs, local)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local)
/dev/ad0s1e on /tmp (ufs, local, soft-updates)
/dev/ad0s1f on /usr (ufs, local, soft-updates)
/dev/ad0s1d on /var (ufs, local, soft-updates)
devfs on /var/named/dev (devfs, local)
```

This is what the lines mean:

```
/dev/ad0s1f <--- is the device
on /usr     <--- path to the file system is /usr
(ufs,       <--- file system on the device
local, soft-updates) <--- other mount options
```

Your disk will probably have the file system ntfs instead of ufs or ext4 or whatever your other disks have.

Note the path to the file system - it is probably something like `/media/nameofdisk` or `/mnt/nameofdisk`.

Now that you have that path, you can change the ownership for all files on the media so that you can access them:

```
sudo find /media/nameofdisk -exec chown yourusername {} \;
find /media/nameofdisk -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

This will make sure that all files and directories on the disks are owned by you and that you can access all directories. If any files on the disks have restricted access permissions, add the following:

```
find /media/nameofdisk -type f -exec o+rw {} \;
```

to add read and write permissions on each file.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is access permission. If the mount point of the drive is `/media/old_drive`, what you could do is:

```
sudo find /media/old_drive -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +
```

This will give everyone permissions to access (and write files into) all directories on that device.

Comment: This is what I typed in the terminal--and the response:  sudo find /BabyDrive -type d -exec chmod 777 {} +
find: `/BabyDrive': No such file or directory
I also tried including the computer name in the path, but got the same result (no such file or directory.

Comment: @Joseph R: the drive displays on my desktop, and all of the folders display when I click on the drive icon. I can access, that is, open some of the folders; the contents seem to be there. I cannot, however, open other folders. When I click on them (and this is the largest folder--approx 12 GB) I see a spinning disk and (I think) the word "processing"above it. Then the computer locks up: the cursor freezes, or doesn't freeze, but I can't close the screen.

Comment: @ganessh it is a SATA drive that I pulled out of my old (and dead) laptop. I popped it into an enclosure, and plan to use it as a backup drive.

Comment: @ganessh -realized I didn't answer your question. It was a drive running Windows 7

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not clear on what isn't clear in/about my question. I've responded to each comment with additional information. Perhaps my challenge is that I'm so new to Linux that I don't have the proper/correct nomenclature to express my challenge. That is the reason I asked--in my original question--what information you would need from me to best provide me with an answer. I thought this was a place for noobs, so please tell me what isn't clear to you all and I will do my best to clarify. Thank you.

Comment: There is at least two question open in comments from JosephR and ganessh. You should update the original question with the answers to that questions, or ask the commentors for additional explanation if you don't understand the question (use `@username` to get there attention). Once you update your Q, ping the commenters with a short comment telling them that you did answer the questions in their comments. Do **not** answer question in comments only, **improve** your question.

Comment: Thank you for this information; I will do so. I am curious, however: did I miss this in the welcome message? Is this information presented in a meta message? If not, how is someone going to know the best and most appropriate way to respond? As well, I did ask in my original msg for just this type of info, and received no reply to that request. I therefore had no way of knowing my question-framing was incorrect. Changing this would be helpful to newcomers. As well, I have never "pinged" anyone, so I would appreciate info on that, as well.

Comment: As well, is your reference to lack of clarity related to the fact that I didn't answer the two questions by editing my question?

Comment: Have you tried to Install the ntfs-3g package ? it will allow you to read and write Without Issue

Comment: No, I've not; this is the first I've heard of it. I will try it now.

Comment: @user250988 I voted to reopen, it is a bit clearer, but you still have not answered the questions posed in the comments below your question. It is OK not to know Linux terminology, but you need to let the commentor know what it is you don't understand, you should do that in a comment. Your filesystem type (asked by ganessh) is still not mentioned in the Q. If you don't know what he means *ask him* in a comment **under his**. It *looks like you did not answer the comments* on the Q and I don't think the system notifies `@username` if you put them under my A if he they have not commented here.

Comment: @user250988 Your filesystem might be NTFS, it certainly is not Windows 7 (that is an operating system). Please realise that e.g. I never ran, let alone installed, Windows 7 on computer. To me because of the freeze, it looks like your disc might be broken. http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx